# Abstract OS environment variables for testing

Tags: rust

I have created a `Server` struct which consists out of 2 ports, an IP address and a port.
The value assigned to the port could NOT be specified, but it's read from the system's environment variables. When the environment variable has not been found, or when it's not a valid value, it defaults to a standard port.

```
struct Server {
    ip: String,
    port: u16,
}

impl Server {
    const STD_PORT: u16 = 4333;
    const PORT_ENV_VAR: &'static str = "MEMDB_PORT";

    fn new(ip: String) -> Server {
        Server {
            ip: ip,
            port: Server::get_port(),
        }
    }

    fn get_port() -> u16 {
        match env::var(Server::PORT_ENV_VAR) {
            Ok(val) => match val.parse::<u16>() {
                Ok(val) => val,
                Err(_) => Server::STD_PORT,
            },
            Err(_) => Server::STD_PORT,
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to create tests for it, it can be done in the following way:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::Server;

    #[test]
    fn test_create_server_assigns_correct_ip() {
        // WHEN:
        let server = crate::Server::new("127.0.0.1".to_owned());

        // THEN:
        assert_eq!(server.ip, "127.0.0.1");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_create_server_assigns_correct_port() {
        // WHEN:
        let server = crate::Server::new("".to_owned());

        // THEN:
        assert_eq!(server.port, 4333);
    }
}
```

Off course, this test produces a different result when the environment variable `MEMDB_PORT` has a value assigned.

How would I be able to verify that the assigned port can be controlled by setting the correct environment variable?

I was thinking about creating a trait that defined the API to access the system's environment variables.

```
trait EnvironmentReader {
    fn get(key: &str) -> Option<String>;
}

struct OSEnvironmentReader {}

impl EnvironmentReader for OSEnvironmentReader {
    fn get(key: &str) -> Option<String> {
        return match env::var(key) {
            Ok(val) => Some(val),
            Err(_) => None,
        };
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way on how to do it in Rust?
If so, how should I modify my struct to use this trait? Add it as a field to the struct itself, and how can I do this with the new 'dyn' stuff?

Comment: You could use std::env::set_var in the test to, well, set the environment variable for the duration of the test.

Comment: That not an optimal solution. If I use the file system instead, you could argue that I can create temporary files in the test to test with but this slows the tests A LOT. I really need a way to mock these dependencies, just looking for the "Rust" way on how to do it.

Comment: In that case you'd probably want some generic configuration handler trait, that you would inject into your server as `Box<dyn Config>` and swap different implementations for testing.

Comment: That's where I have some issues. I have a trait (see my code, but don't know how to use it correctly, with the box thing...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `dyn` or traits here. Simply create a configuration struct:

```
pub struct ServerConfig {
    pub port: u16,
}

impl ServerConfig {
    const STD_PORT: u16 = 4333;
    const PORT_ENV_VAR: &'static str = "MEMDB_PORT";

    fn from_environment() -> ServerConfig {
        ServerConfig {
            port: Self::port_from_env(),
        }
    }

    fn port_from_env() -> u16 {
        // Also shortened the `match` a bit here. Could make this generic too.
        env::var(ServerConfig::PORT_ENV_VAR)
            .map(|val| val.parse::<u16>())
            .unwrap_or(ServerConfig::STD_PORT)
    }
}
```

Then pass it into your `Server` when constructing it:

```
struct Server {
    config: Config,
    ip: String,
}

impl Server {
    fn new(config: Config, ip: String) -> Server {
        Server {
            config,
            ip,
        }
    }
}
```

In production code, pass `ServerConfig::from_environment()`. In your test code, pass a custom `ServerConfig { port: 4333 }`. You're still not testing whether the port is correctly taken from the environment, but in the comments you mentioned that you didn't want that and would rather mock it out.

You could also move `ip` into `ServerConfig` if it fits better with your design.

Comment: Thanks. Zeeman that I was indeed overcomplicating things ....

Comment: There's one issue I see here, and that's that I don't have a way to test that the default port is returned when the value in the environment variable is not a valid u16. Would it be benificial to use traits to cover this case? If so, could you update your answer?

Comment: You could pass a function (`FnOnce`) into `from_environment`. In production, pass `std::env::var`, and in tests, pass a lambda that returns a fixed value. Instead of a function you can also use a trait, e.g. `fn from_environment<G: VarGetter>(var_getter: V)` with `trait VarGetter { fn get_var(&self, name: &str) -> Result<String, Error>; }` or something along those lines. With one implementation for production that just calls `std::env::var`, and a mock for tests that returns whatever.